# Why is ajaxStop() not firing in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first time using ajax. and i don't have an idea where the ajaxStop takes place. I am using the ajaxStart to show a loading image and need the ajaxStop to hide the loading image. Please help.

I have this code to call a popup from "PageOne"

```
function ShowFixSteps(path, title){
  var winHeight = parseInt(jQuery(window).height() - 100);
  var winWidth = parseInt(jQuery(window).width() - 600);

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: path,
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#divPopup").load(path).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: winWidth,
        height: winHeight,
        title: title,
        position: "center"
      });
    }
  });

  jQuery("#divPopup").bind("dialogbeforeclose", function(){
    jQuery("#divPopup").empty('');
  });
}
```

And on my Master page, I have this code to check the start and stop of ajax call:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  alert('start');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  alert('stop');
});

$(document).ajaxError(function() {
  alert('error');
});
```

It alerts the START but not the STOP: no ERROR also.

NOTE: START and STOP alerts are working on Chrome but not IE.

Comment: ajax stop only triggers after all ajax requests finish running. If you have a recurring ajax request anywhere in your code that starts before the previous stops, ajax stop will never trigger.

Comment: @Eytch, see my updated answer for IE problem.

Answer (score 2):

`ajaxStop` is triggered after all current AJAX requests have completed.

You can read more about `ajaxStop` using [the jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

Comment: @KevinB Woops, fixed my answer. Haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: thank you both for your response kehrk and @KevinB. i don't remember having another ajax call but is it possible to may be force stop all ajax call after my codes inside SUCCESS?

Comment: @Eytch only if you have access to all of the ajax calls so you can iterate over them and call .abort on each one.

Comment: @Eytch Exactly what Kevin said. You can store them in a collection, which I *believe* is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: sorry, my bad. i just checked and found out my code is working on chrome. problem happens on IE. updated my question. but what seems to be the prob with IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ajaxStop()` in the following manner:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loading-spinner').hide();
});
```

Or you could add `:complete` callback to your AJAX function, like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: path,
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#divPopup").load(path).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: winWidth,
        height: winHeight,
        title: title,
        position: "center"
      });
    },
    complete: function() {
        // do something here when ajax stops
        // like hiding the spinner or calling another function
    }
  });
```

And as you mentioned how to stop an AJAX request in one of your comments, here's how:

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    ...
});

ajax1.abort()
```

You could check if a specific AJAX request is running before aborting by doing this:

```
if (ajax1) {
    ajax1.abort();
}
```

Or you could check to see if *any* ajax requests are running before aborting by doing something like this:

```
var ajax_inprocess = false;
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    ajax_inprocess = true;
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    ajax_inprocess = false;
});

if (ajax_inprocess == true) {
    request.abort();
}
```

Beware using `.abort()` though, as it only stops the client-side code from listening for a response, it wont actually stop the server from working. There are actually a few major caveats using this, so make sure you read about it first.

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR UPDATED QUESTION**

For IE problem, try using:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // do something
})
```

Instead of `ajaxStop()`. `ajaxComplete()` will fire each time an AJAX request finishes, rather than when ALL requests have finished using `ajaxStop()`. Maybe it will help, maybe not.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response.. the suggested code seems to be alright. however, $(document).ajaxStop is not triggered in IE. i'm wondering what seems to be the prob when it works on Chrome

Comment: thanks! it's having a progress. however, the ajaxComplete is being called right before my Popup is displayed. if it is possible, i need the loading image to be hidden AFTER all popup contents are loaded